# Add UITableView over an UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tableview, addsubview

I have 3 UIViewController. 
First One : ParentViewController with 1 UITableView.
Second : CollectionViewController with 1 other UITableView.
Third : UserViewController with a button which load my first UITableView.

I would like my tableviews over the half of my view in my UserViewController when i click on the button.

I do that but my UserViewController is hiding with a black background:

```
ParentTableViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
[self.view addSubview:transferViewController.tableView];
```

How can I do ?
I'm using segues and storyboard, i don't have navigation controller.